# ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Other element would receive the click - Click Element or Button Failing in Robot

Tags: selenium, automation, robotframework, ui-automation

Click Element or Click Button is not working in Robot Framework.

Simple Code Block for Login page

```
    ${chromeOptions}=    Create Dictionary  acceptInsecureCerts=${True}
    Open Browser  ${url}  ${browser}  desired_capabilities=${chromeOptions}
    Maximize Browser Window
    sleep  5s
    Wait Until Page Contains  Welcome to Mavenir CMS.
    Input Text  name:user name  ${username}
    Input Text  name:password  ${password}
    Wait Until Page Contains Element  xpath://button[@type="submit"]
    Click Button  xpath://button[@type="submit"]
#    Press Keys  \  ENTER
    sleep  15s
    Wait Until Page Contains Element  xpath:${home_settings}
```

Actually the same code was working till the previous version of same dashboard. Now am getting the error while trying to Click Element

The code passes till     `Wait Until Page Contains Element  xpath://button[@type="submit"]`
The element is loaded and its available but when I try to click it, its not happenening.

I have tried providing different ways of locators like below for the same button:

xpath://button[contains(text(),'Login')]

class:btn-primary

xpath:/html/body/my-app/div/headerapp/div/div[2]/login/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/form/div[3]/button[1]

css:body > my-app > div > header-app > div > div.col-md-12 > login > div.login-overlay > div > div > div.login-right.pull-right > form > div.group.pull-top-2 > button.btn-primary

and the one seen in the code block above.
All these are returning the same exception --> ElementClickInterceptedException

I have tried adding sleeps in between also and still same issue.

One thing that worked is, instead if Click Element/Button, I gave `Press Keys  \\  ENTER`

It worked and login was successful but once logged in to the dashboard, again when I try to click on any other elements/tabs inside, getting the same exception. So basically I was able to everything other than Click operation but Clicking is the most important thing that is needed.

Unable to find the solution to this. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: There is no problem with Robot Framework but the way that you are interacting with the webpage.
Take a closer look at the error, usually selenium will give you the object that is receiving the click and that will be a clue on what is going on.
It could be several things, a popup on screen, its not visible in the ui, etc, so without the webpage code its impossible to point the error

Comment: Thanks for your response Claudio.
<div _ngcontent-c5="" class="group pull-top-2">
                        <button _ngcontent-c5="" class="btn-primary" type="submit" xpath="1">Login</button>
                        <button _ngcontent-c5="" class="btn-custom-reset" role="button" style="margin-left:5px;" type="reset">Reset</button>
                        
                    </div>

This is the webpage element code that am trying to click in this example.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when a page loads for a brief moment and then the element disappears for a loader or any async request.

```
Wait Until Page Contains Element   xpath://button[@type="submit"]
Wait Until Element Is Visible    xpath://button[@type="submit"]
Sleep    2s #This could be adjusted as per the time your application takes to load after first appearing. Usually this should be enough.
Wait Until Element Is Visible    xpath://button[@type="submit"]
Sleep    2s
Wait Until Element Is Enabled    xpath://button[@type="submit"]
Click Element    xpath://button[@type="submit"]
```

Also, use `Click Element` instead of `Click Button`. Sometimes, *very rarely,* even though the element is a button, `Click Button` doesen't work.

Comment: Thanks for replying Avtar. I tried this out but even now, Wait until Element Is Enabled line is executed fine but still the next Click Element line throws the same exception..
<div _ngcontent-c5="" class="group pull-top-2">
                        <button _ngcontent-c5="" class="btn-primary" type="submit" xpath="1">Login</button>
                        <button _ngcontent-c5="" class="btn-custom-reset" role="button" style="margin-left:5px;" type="reset">Reset</button>
                        
                    </div>

This is the webpage element am trying to click in this example

Comment: Made edits to the code. Please check. I believe using `Wait until element is visible` in conjuncture with `Wait Until Page Contains Element` and `Wait Until Element Is Enabled` should solve this issue.